Prove that $A \leq G^2$, where $A$ is the arithmetic mean and $G$ is the geometric mean.
I know that $G \leq A$ where $G = \sqrt[n]{a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \cdot \cdot a_n} \ $ and $ \ A = \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n} \ $ and $ \ 1 \leq a_1, a_2, ... , a_n \leq n$ (this is given to me for this specific exercise). I have to show that $A \leq G^2$.
I don't know how to proceed. I would like a hint on how to start or what method to use. I would like to solve this on my own but I don't know how to start.

Hint $G^2=A\times H$, since all $a_i\geq 1$, $H\geq 1$

@EDX Assuming $H$ is the harmonic mean, that only holds for $n=2$.

Yes true man true

This is false as stated. Indeed, if one of the variables is $n$ and the rest are $1$, then $A \geq 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ and $G^2 = n^{2/n}$. When $n \geq 10$, we have $A > G^2$.
To fix this problem, we can tighten the range on $a_i$ to $a_i \in [1, \lambda]$. The function $f: [1, \lambda]^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(a_1, \cdots, a_n) = \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} - (a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{2/n}$$
is convex in each variable, so its maximum value is assumed at one of the vertices of $[1, n]^n$. Thus, to show that $f$ is not positive, it suffices to check this when $t$ of the $a_i$'s are $\lambda$ and the rest are $1$. In this case, we have
$$f(1, \cdots,1,\lambda,\cdots,\lambda) = \frac{t\lambda + (n - \lambda)}{n} - \lambda^{2t / n} = 1 + \frac{\lambda - 1}{n} t - \lambda^{2t / n}.$$
Using $e^x \geq x + 1$, we have
$$f(1, \cdots,1,\lambda,\cdots,\lambda) \leq \frac{\lambda - 1}{n} t - \frac{2\log \lambda}{n} t.$$
Thus, the problem would hold if $a_i \in [1, \lambda]$ with $\lambda - 1 = 2\log \lambda$, or $\lambda \approx 3.51$.
